# Flask WTForms Form automatic inline style display: None

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I have the following html/jinja and the following WTForm

```
<form method="POST" action='' class="form" >
{% for field in form %}
    {{ render_field(field) }}
{% endfor %}
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Login</button>
```

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
username = StringField(
    'username',
    validators=[
        DataRequired()
    ]
)

password = PasswordField(
    'Password',
    validators=[
        DataRequired()
    ])

{% macro render_field(field, class="", div_class="") %}
<div class="field {{ div_class }}">
    {% if field.errors %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
             <div class="notification error">{{ error }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ field(placeholder=field.label.text, class=class) }}
</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

The form is passed into the template as form. When the view is loaded an inline style of display: None is automatically added to the form. I can change this using chrome dev tools and everything functions properly. I am in need of some help in determining why this is occurring.

The following html is what is sent to the browser.

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="form" style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the "Styles" tab within the in-browser Developer Tools?

Here's an image of the specific pane I'm referring to.

[Image: Dev Tools Style Pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUFqe.png)

I know you said you've gone in there and edited on the fly, but the "Styles" pane should also be able to tell you which file each style rule is set in, which can hopefully give you some more information to help track down the problem.

Comment: Hmm. There is no file associated with the style. I'm pretty confused.

Comment: Ya I have nothing in my css setting display to none. Something server side must be telling it to set an inline style to display: none?

Comment: Hmmm my only other immediate solution is to test what happens if you remove "class='form'" as there might be a name conflict, but I can keep poking around

Comment: If it's helpful to know, your code above works properly for me in an isolated test case using Flask / Jinja / Bootstrap

Comment: Looks like the issue was fixed by deleting "class='for'". Thanks Emjabs!